# Using datepicker altField on different pages. Is this possible?

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

My question: is it even possible to use altField on another page and (hopefully yes) can someone show me the correct direction?

```
var opts = {
 dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    dayNamesMin: ['Zo', 'Ma', 'Di', 'Wo', 'Do', 'Vr', 'Za'],
    minDate: '+0D',
    maxDate: '+2Y',
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "/img/datepicker-icon.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText:"Selecteer datum",
};

//on homepage
$('#from').datepicker( $.extend({ altField: '#alt-from'}, opts));
$('#to').datepicker($.extend({altField: '#alt-to'}, opts));

//on contact page
$('#alt-from').datepicker( $.extend({ altField: '#from'}, opts));
$('#alt-to').datepicker($.extend({altField: '#to'}, opts));
```

Comment: found solution on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values